# How to resolve the Java Memory Heap issue for for each block

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

I am trying to insert the documents in MongoDB Database by using below syntax.The below code is throwing Java Memory Heap space exception .In for loop at this step  documentList.add(Document.parse(dbObject.toJson()); throwing the Java Heap Memory issue .I have tried increasing the memory but still it is throwing the Memory issue .Can anyone assist on this how to avoid the Java Heap issue in for loop

```
private void NextMonth(String system , String period) {
        {
         

            String nextPeriod = Utilities.Period(period);
           
           List<? extends Bson> pipeline  = Arrays.asList(
                    new Document()
                            .append("$match", new Document()
                                    .append("key", "PP")
                                    .append("AmountType", "IN")
                                    .append("key", system)
                                    .append("period", period)
                            ),
                    new Document()
                            .append("$addFields", new Document()
                                    .append("ID", "$_id")
                                    .append("Period", nextPeriod)
                                    .append("Transaction", nextPeriod)
                                    .append("Reporting", nextPeriod)
                                    
                                    .append("Type", new Document()
                                            .append("key", "XX")
                                            .append("value", "OutStanding Amount")
                                    )
                                    .append("amount", new Document()
                                            .append("$multiply", Arrays.asList(
                                                    "$Amount.amount",
                                                    Decimal128.parse("-1.0")
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )
                                    .append("OriginalAmt", new Document()
                                            .append("$multiply", Arrays.asList(
                                                    "$amount",
                                                    Decimal128.parse("-1.0")
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )
                                    .append("TransactionAmt.amount", new Document()
                                            .append("$multiply", Arrays.asList(
                                                    "$amount",
                                                    Decimal128.parse("-1.0")
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )
                                    .append("amount", new Document()
                                            .append("$multiply", Arrays.asList(
                                                    "$amount",
                                                    Decimal128.parse("-1.0")
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )
                                   
                            ),
                   
            );

            AggregateIterable<Document> response =  collectionDB.aggregate(pipeline).allowDiskUse(false);
          

            List documentList = new ArrayList();
            for (Document dbObject : response)
            {
                // System.out.println(dbObject);
                documentList.add(Document.parse(dbObject.toJson());
              //  System.out.println(dbObject);
            }
            mergeCollection.insertMany(documentList);
```

StackTrace :

j

```
ava.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:407)
    at org.bson.json.JsonScanner.scanString(JsonScanner.java:511)
    at org.bson.json.JsonScanner.nextToken(JsonScanner.java:88)
    at org.bson.json.JsonReader.popToken(JsonReader.java:492)
    at org.bson.json.JsonReader.visitExtendedJSON(JsonReader.java:596)
    at org.bson.json.JsonReader.readBsonType(JsonReader.java:148)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:149)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:45)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.LazyCodec.decode(LazyCodec.java:47)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.readValue(DocumentCodec.java:222)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:151)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:45)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.readValue(DocumentCodec.java:222)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.readList(DocumentCodec.java:229)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.readValue(DocumentCodec.java:218)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:151)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:45)
    at org.bson.Document.parse(Document.java:105)
    at org.bson.Document.parse(Document.java:90)
    at com.agcs.cids.RestController.NextMonth(RestController.java:256)
    at com.agcs.cids.RestController.getMonthDetails(RestController.java:89)
    at com.agcs.cids.RestController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a48dec59.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.agcs.cids.MonthEndRestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$df52defb.getMonthDetails(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2021-11-30 09:23:36.087  INFO 1 --- [v.allianz:27018] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.createBsonReader(ProtocolHelper.java:145) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getOperationTime(ProtocolHelper.java:114) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.updateSessionContext(InternalStreamConnection.java:517) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:291) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:38) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:180) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:124) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_262]
```

Comment: Could you attach the stack trace as well? Is the `Document` class something you created or is it from another library? If it's your's attach that as well

Comment: Insert individual ones, not all of them. If you have a large resultset you don't want to keep everything in memory.

Comment: @k9yosh :Added Stack trace . And Document is org.bson public class Document extends Object implements Map<String, Object>, Serializable, Bson .Please have a look and suggest how to resolve the Java Heap Memory space issue and insert the documents in MongoDB collection

Comment: @M.Deinum :How Can I insert the individual ones .Can you please help me with the syntax to insert the individual ones

Comment: Call `insert` inside the loop on the `mergecollection` instead of `insertMany`. Don't stuff them in the list, just store it directly.

Comment: @M.Deinum  , Thank you so much .Java Heap Memory issue is resolved and I am able to insert the data into MongoDB database .

Comment: @M.Deinum , I have multiple systems and period , In case if the input comes with the same system and with the same period the data should not get inserted into Database .How Can I achieve that scenario

Comment: Not sure what you want with that? Check database if already exists don't insert. Not sure how else you would do that. Or keep a small set (not list) of combinations of `system/period` you already have and check that.